# Increasing marker size based on number of points at same location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, style, clustering, qgis-custom-function

I have a dataset that contains many points (representing specimens) with GPS locations taken at the same point. When I map these points as a vector layer, only the uppermost point shows - so, at one given location, for example, there could be 50 data points yet it looks exactly the same as a location that may have just 1 data point.

I am wondering if there is a way to increase the marker size relatively to show this abundance of points at the same location using QGIS? I have tried to use the point displacement tool but I am not looking for the result that this gives with a centroid and a ring of points surrounding. I basically want to create a buffer that has a size in accordance with the number of points at that same lat long to show the relative abundance of specimens at that point.

[image: here is a screen shot, the different colors are classified based on time, the points in the southern/coastal area of NH have A LOT of points whereas the northern area has fewer points]

Comment: I tried to solve the issue using a geometry generator, please see my answer and let me know if it works (the solution is explained in detail and it is really easy to apply).

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought of styling the data as a heatmap. This way areas of concentration will show up as more intense colors. I am not sure what program you are using but this can be done quite simply using QGIS. A good tutorial explaining the process can be found at http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html.

Answer (score 2):

I propose an approach which only recurs to a geometry generator and a custom function.

---

Firstly, go to `Layer Properties | Style` and then choose the `Single symbol` renderer.

From the `Symbol selector` dialog, choose a `Geometry generator` as symbol layer type and `Polygon / MultiPolygon` as geometry type. Then, click on the `Function Editor` tab:

[image]

Then, click on `New file` and type `buff_numb` as the name of the new function:

[image]

You will see that a new function has been created and it is listed on the left side of the dialog. Now, click on the name of the function and replace the default `@qgsfunction` with the following code (don't delete the libraries imported by default):

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def buff_numb(layer_name, curr_feat, feature, parent):
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)

    tmp_geom = curr_feat.geometry()
    idsList = index.intersects(tmp_geom.boundingBox())
    return len(idsList)
```

Once you have done this, click on the `Load` button and you will be able to see the function from the `Custom` Menu of the `Expression` dialog.

Now, type this expression (see the image below as a reference):

```py
buffer(
 $geometry,
 0.04 * buff_numb(@layer_name, $currentfeature)
)
```

[image]

You have just run a function which is saying, in an imaginary way:

> *"For the current layer (**@layer_name**) and the current feature (**$currentfeature**), display its geometry using a buffer having a radius of 0.04 decimal degrees times the number of occurrences."*

The only thing you need to change is the value of the radius: I expressed it in decimal degrees since you wrote about lat/lon, so I assumed you were using a Geographic Reference System (if not, this is not a problem and you can set any value you want). Therefore, leave the other function parameters as provided.

Finally, click on the `Apply` button for applying the changes.

You will see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided here by mgri (which I think would work great in QGIS 2) unfortunately won't work in QGIS 3 as the `QgsMapLayerRegistry` is no longer recognized (please see [Is QgsMapLayerRegistry removed in QGIS3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244452/is-qgsmaplayerregistry-removed-in-qgis3?)).

QGIS 3 now includes a point cluster renderer that will accomplish this same result out-of-the-box, without additional coding: https://north-road.com/2016/09/06/point-cluster-renderer-crowdfunding-successful/

Video explaining how to setup and configure is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNL-ZSlc4KM

Also please see here: https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/13/even-more-aggregations-qgis-point-cluster-renderer/

Comment: Can you include a summary from the links?